# Version backups and restoring latest backup with robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am trying to write a batch file and use the `robocopy` command to backup a directory. However, I need multiple backups to be kept. Let's say I have a directory `"A"` in `"C:\Source Path"` and a backup location `"C:\Backup Path"`.

I need the following to happen:
During the backup, If `"C:\Backup Path\A Dir"` already exists then the copy result should make `"C:\Backup Path\A Dir2"`; or a similar numbering system.
During the restore, the highest-numbered backup directory in `"C:\Backup Path"` should replace `"C:\Original Path\A Dir"`

My current script does not do any versioning and looks like below:

```
@echo off
set originalPath="C:\Original Path\A"
set backupPath="C:\Backup Path\A"
:L1
echo 1. Backup save files
echo 2. Restore save files
echo 3. Exit
set /p choice=Select an option: 
if %choice% equ 1 goto :BACKUP
if %choice% equ 2 goto :RESTORE
if %choice% equ 3 goto :EOF
goto :L1

:BACKUP
robocopy %originalPath% %backupPath% /E
goto :L1

:RESTORE
robocopy %backupPath% %originalPath% /E
goto :L1
:EOF
```

Is such an operation possible using `robocopy` alone?

Comment: No, there is no versioning, or incrementing, (either integer or alphabet characters) in Robocopy.exe. There is however, a `choice.exe` utility, which should be used for simple single key option entry, not that non robust implementation of the `Set` command with its `/P` option. In addition to that, `gamePath` is not defined.

Comment: Whilst you're at it, you should remove the `:EOF` label. `GoTo :EOF` is a special instruction for End Of File, (or Call), it does not seek a label..